# SQl Pivot help with multiple tables

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

**SQL Pivot Help:**
I have three tables as follows:
*Class Table:*

```
ID Name
1   N1
2   N2
3   N3
```

*Flags Table:*

```
ID  ClassID  Flags
1      1       F1
1      1       F2
1      2       F3
1      3       F1
1      3       F3
```

*Session Table:*

```
ID   ClassID  Session
1       1       S1
2       1       S2
3       1       S3
4       2       S2
5       2       S5
6       3       S1
6       3       S2
```

Now I need to create a view something like this:

*Class View:*

```
ID  Name       Flags       Session
1    N1        F1,F2       S1,S2,S3
2    N2          F3          S2,S5
3    N3        F1,F3         S1,S2
```

Comment: PIVOT is one thing that just about every database implements differently. Without specifying the database and version, you'll most likely get few if any responses to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to create the comma separated lists in the presentation layer of the client.  You can join the tables together like:

```
select 
    class.id
,   class.name
,   flags.flags
,   session.session
from class
left join flags on flags.classid = class.id
left join session on session.classid = class.id
```

Although databases are not meant to format data, most databases support some way of generating comma separated lists.  For example, in MySQL, you can use `group_concat`:

```
select 
    class.id
,   class.name
,   group_concat(flags.flags separator ',')
,   group_concat(session.session separator ',')
from class
left join flags on flags.classid = class.id
left join session on session.classid = class.id
group by class.id, class.name
```

If you're using another DMBS, please add it to your question.

Comment: For SQL Server, the usual approach is a `for xml` trick, see http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html

Answer (score 1):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005), I figured out the following:

```
select fs.ClassId
    , fs.ClassName
    , LEFT(fs.Flags, LEN(fs.Flags) - 2) as Flags
    , LEFT(fs.Sessions, LEN(fs.Sessions) - 2) as Sessions
from (
    select c.Id as ClassId
            , c.[Name] as ClassName
            , (
                select Flags + N', ' as [text()]
                    from FlagsTable
                    where ClassId = c.Id
                    FOR XML PATH (N'')
            ) as Flags
            , (
                select Session + N', ' as [text()]
                    from SessionTable
                    where ClassId = c.Id
                    FOR XML PATH (N'')
            ) as Sessions
        from ClassTable c
    ) fs
```